# Do I need different PWA instances for different project teams?

Tags: sharepoint-server, pwa, project

Suppose we have two teams A and B working on different projects. Each team has its own managers, leads and members. And I want each team to have access only to their own projects while admin (me) must be able to monitor the progress of all projects. How should I manage to do this? Should I create two PWA apps or different site collections?